# Attempts in uploading video in vimeo

Tags: vimeo-api, vimeo-android

I have to upload video to vimeo,I am using resumable PUT uploads in which I have uploaded video, then get a 200 response code.Thereafter I verify the upload but the range that api is returning is not the size of my file size.
so how many attempts can we make to achieve a complete 100% upload of our video file.. So that we can make a delete call???

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit to the amount of attempts you can make, but your next request should resume where the first one left off until the entire file is uploaded.

eg:

1. You upload a 100mb video
2. You verify the bytes uploaded, but Vimeo claims you have only uploaded 50mb
3. You upload bytes 51 through 100
4. You verify the bytes upload, but Vimeo claims you have only uploaded a total of 90mb including step 1.
5. You upload bytes 91 through 100
6. You verify the bytes uploaded, and Vimeo claims it has received 100mb
7. You perform the "delete" call to wrap up the upload flow.

The verification/resume loop can happen any number of times.

Comment: Thank you Dashron ,I have followed your steps ,but in that case DELETE call gives me null response (No location parameter in Header). Please guide me I can't figure out why is it happening so??

Comment: "This video will be available shortly" this is the message displayed when we try to view our uploaded video.